# Google+ Over-The-Air Installs doesn't work

Tags: android, google-plus, over-the-air

I'm trying to make Google+ Over-The-Air Installs working (https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/android-app-installs)

I added Client ID for my Android app and for web app into Google apis frontend and added data-`apppackagename` parameter to button. I would expect new dialog box appear right after regular G+ log-in dialog.

**Is anybody got this feature working??!**

My html:

```
<script>AsyncRequest('https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=start')
    function signInCallback(authResult) {
        if (authResult['code']) {
            alert('oki-doki');
        }
    }
</script>
    <!-- Add where you want your sign-in button to render -->
<div id="signinButton">
  <span class="g-signin"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
    data-clientid="XXXXXX"
    data-redirecturi="postmessage"
    data-accesstype="offline"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-apppackagename="com.tfd.mobile.TfdSearch"
    data-callback="signInCallback">
  </span>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**ADDED:**

Does I right understand that over-the-air install window should appears right after auth popup and before my `signInCallback` js got fired?

Comment: What is the link to your app in the Play Store?

Comment: BrettJ, this is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tfd.mobile.TfdSearch. BTW, it's pretty clear from `data-apppackagename` which I provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added some [troubleshooting info to Over the air installs page](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/android-app-installs#testing_android_app_installs_for_your_web_site) that might help out. It does look like your app should meet the qualifications required for the feature to be available.

My guess is that Google Play store believes that you have the app installed or possibly still have it on another device that you use and so its not triggering. It could also be that you tried it out and the system was still caching that you had it installed.

Comment: Thank you for help. It turns out that there are enormous amount of both testing and mine devices attached to my account. It was impossible to remove the app from all these devices, some of them doesn't exists anymore. So, I simple create new Google Account solely for this testing purpose and it's indeed works! Thank you again, your addition to "over-the-air install page" page was also very handy.

Comment: How does one know that their app has passed the qualifications required for OTA installs?

Comment: I don't get it, i tried it with a minimal setup exactly as described in the installation guide (for web). 

But always the window just opens and i can enter my credentials but the windows is closing again. As like it behaves as with the default sign in.

https://jsfiddle.net/7vo45enh/2/

Answer (score 0):

If your app is new, or still in development, it may not trigger the Over-the-Air Install feature, yet.  There is a minimum "quality" threshold that the app must meet before the dialog will trigger. This threshold is determined by the Android Play Store.  If your app is new, then you can set up the install feature by adding in the package name, and it will trigger the dialog in the future once your app passes the threshold.  In the meantime, you can be assured that by adding the correct package name, the set up is complete.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant as soon as the app has 100K+ reviews. Do you have you app works with this feature? Does I right understand that over-the-air install window should appears right after auth popup and before my `signInCallback` js fired.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the ones mentioned above, another reason could be the OAuth keys being generated from different Google Projects.

I was using the keys from two different projects and it did not work. Then I changed both the Web "Login with Google" Web Client Keys and Android OAuth API keys from the same project, and it worked.